# Plotting two dataframe columns with the third as x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
    type_of_thing  group1      group 2
0        type1     0.030659    0.052632
1        type2     0.099169    0.026316
2        type3     0.184580    0.236842
3        type4     0.469446    0.605263
```

What I want to do is compare each type across group one and group 2. The graph I want is kind of like this:
[image]
(quickly made in excel, but I'm generating the dataframe I'm using within the script)

The code I have is this:

```
import seaborn as sns
...
rest of code
...
sns.catplot(x='type_of_thing', y=group1,kind="bar", data=df)
```

Alternatively I have this code:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

But that shows up like this, ignoring the type_of_thing column altogether when I want the type_of_thing column to be used as labels for the x axis:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix one or both of these pieces of code to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you might need to melt your dataframe to get it in the right shape, then you should be able to use `group` as your x, and `type_of_thing` as your hue

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'type_of_thing': ['type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'],
 'group1': [0.030659, 0.09916900000000001, 0.18458, 0.46944600000000003],
 'group2': [0.052632000000000005, 0.026316000000000003, 0.236842, 0.605263]})


df = df.melt(id_vars='type_of_thing', var_name='group')
# So you can see what happened with melt and why it helps here
print(df)

sns.catplot(data=df, x='group',y='value', kind='bar', hue='type_of_thing')
```

This is what the melted df looks like:

```
  type_of_thing   group     value
0         type1  group1  0.030659
1         type2  group1  0.099169
2         type3  group1  0.184580
3         type4  group1  0.469446
4         type1  group2  0.052632
5         type2  group2  0.026316
6         type3  group2  0.236842
7         type4  group2  0.605263
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! (I had to switch the y and hue columns to get the output I wanted but it worked great.)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)